# Can I delete any line with a given search string?

Tags: vim, find-and-replace

In Vim, I'd like to search for lines with a given string, then delete them.

Specifically, I'd like to find lines with the LaTeX commands `\begin{frame}` and `\end{frame}`, and delete them. =

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Use the `g` command to operate on lines matching a pattern, along with the `d` command to delete those lines.

```
g/pattern/d
```

So:

```
g/\\\(begin\|end\){frame}/d
```

should do the trick.

If that doesn't work, try:

```
:g/\v\\(begin|end)\{frame\}/d
```

which will work, no matter what your `magic` setting is.

Comment: Thanks! The `g` is the trick I needed to learn!